# is it possible to write/run BigQuery on parquet files on AWS S3?

Tags: google-bigquery

We want to check BigQuery performance on external store parquet files. These parquet  files are store on AWS S3. Without transfering files to GCP, Is possible to write BigQuery which can run on AWS S3 stored parquet files dataset.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. BigQuery supports "external tables" where the data exists as files in **Google Cloud Storage** but no other cloud file store is supported, including AWS S3.

You will need to either copy/move the files from S3 to Cloud Storage and then use BigQuery on them, or use a similar AWS service such as Athena to query the files in situ on S3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [BigQuery Data Transfer Service for Amazon S3](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/s3-transfer-intro) which allows you to automatically schedule and manage recurring loads jobs from Amazon S3 into BigQuery and allows loading data in Parquet format. In this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/s3-transfer) you will find the documentation on how to set up an Amazon S3 data transfer.